# cell background image with text itextsharp

Tags: c#, file, pdf, itext, cell

Thanks in advance , I know that you're busy .. so I edited this based on the code you gave me ... 
first I want you to see what I got when I tried you code ..

[image]

and the picture I used as a background is :

[image]

as you see I got several problems :

1- the image is not a background to the cells and I want it to be stretched .

2- I tried to put the text in different positions but I failed .

3 - also i got a missing cell  that not showed.

the code I used is :

1- the ImageEvent class  :

```
 class ImageEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
protected Image img;
public ImageEvent(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
}
 void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
{
    img.ScaleToFit(position.Width, position.Height);

    img.SetAbsolutePosition(position.Left + (position.Width - img.Width) / 2,
            position.Bottom + (position.Height - img.ScaledHeight / 2));
    PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
    try {
        canvas.AddImage(img);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

}

2- The position class :

```
 class PositionEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    protected Phrase content;
    protected string pos;

    public PositionEvent(Phrase content, string pos)
    {
        this.content = content;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

     void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        int alignment = 0;
        switch (pos)
        {
            case "TOP_LEFT":
                x = position.GetLeft(3);
                y = position.GetTop(content.Leading);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                break;
            case "TOP_RIGHT":
                x = position.GetRight(3);
                y = position.GetTop(content.Leading);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
            case "BOTTOM_LEFT":
                x = position.GetLeft(3);
                y = position.GetBottom(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                break;
            case "BOTTOM_RIGHT":
                x = position.GetRight(3);
                y = position.GetBottom(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
            case "CENTER_TOP":
                x = position.GetRight(3) + position.GetLeft(3) / 2; 
                y = position.GetTop(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
            case "CENTER_BOTTOM":
                x = position.GetRight(3) + position.GetLeft(3) / 2;
                y = position.GetBottom(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
            case "CENTER_MIDDLE":
                x = position.GetRight(3) + position.GetLeft(3) / 2;
                y = x;
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
        }
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, alignment, content, x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

3- The method :

```
  public void createPdf(string dest)
    {
        // 1. Create a Document which contains a table:
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100f;
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell();
        // 2. Inside that table, make each cell with specific height:
        cell1.FixedHeight=50;
        cell2.FixedHeight = 50;
        cell3.FixedHeight = 50;
        cell4.FixedHeight = 50;
        cell5.FixedHeight = 50;
        cell6.FixedHeight = 50;
        cell7.FixedHeight = 50;
        // 3. Each cell has the same background image
        string path = string.Concat(this.openFileDialog_pic.FileName);
        string imageFilePath = string.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("."), path);
        iTextSharp.text.Image IMG = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);

        ImageEvent imgEvent = new ImageEvent(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(IMG));
        cell1.CellEvent=imgEvent;
        cell2.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        cell3.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        cell4.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        cell5.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        cell6.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        cell7.CellEvent = imgEvent;
        // 4. Add text in front of the image at specific position
        cell1.CellEvent= new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Top left"), "TOP_LEFT");
        cell2.CellEvent=new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Top right"), "TOP_RIGHT");
        cell3.CellEvent=new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Bottom left"), "BOTTOM_LEFT");
        cell4.CellEvent=new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Bottom right"), "BOTTOM_RIGHT");
        cell5.CellEvent = new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Center Top"), "CENTER_TOP");
        cell6.CellEvent = new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Center Bottom"), "CENTER_BOTTOM");
        cell7.CellEvent = new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Center Middle"), "CENTER_MIDDLE");
        // Wrap it all up!
        table.AddCell(cell1);
        table.AddCell(cell2);
        table.AddCell(cell3);
        table.AddCell(cell4);
        table.AddCell(cell5);
        table.AddCell(cell6);
        table.AddCell(cell7);
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. I see that you use a `PdfPCellEvent` named `CellBackgroundEvent`. I assume that you are adding the image as a background in this class. You didn't share that code, so I assume that's working. You shared the `GetCard()` method that seems to create a nested table, but you don't tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: the problem is I cant control the position of the text i get from 'GetCard()' method .. so I tried padding as you see .. I put the text for example on the top or the middle of the cell .. but padding is not accurate

Comment: That's still inaccurate. Nobody but you knows what you expect. If you ask someone else to help you, please understand that we can't look into your mind. Clarify. Make a drawing. Explain!

Comment: Thanks for replying ... and sorry for the misleading.. 
So I'll try to make it as simple as I can ...
forget all the coding I've written .... 
1- I want to create a  document which contains one table.. 
Inside that table ,cells .... 
2- I want to make each cell with specific height 
3- each cell have the same background image . 
4- I want to put a text in front the image in the position I want inside the cell . For example : top left of the cell , bottom right of the cell ..etc 
........ I did 1,2 and 3 .. but I couldn't do 4 ..

Comment: I hope I was clear last comment ... please I need help @ BrunoLowagie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an additional comment, you clarify your requirements:

1. I want to create a document which contains one table. Inside that table, cells
2. I want to make each cell with specific height
3. each cell have the same background image
4. I want to put a text in front the image in the position I want inside the cell. For example: top left of the cell, bottom right of the cell

In other words: you want something like this: [position_content_in_cell.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/position_content_in_cell.pdf)

[image]

There is more than one way to do this. I don't understand the code sample you use in your question. It uses nested tables and I don't understand why you'd need nested tables.

In the [`PositionContentInCell`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/PositionContentInCell) example, I used a method that allows you to really fine-tune the exact position of the text. I created an `ImageEvent` to scale and center the image:

```
class ImageEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected Image img;
    public ImageEvent(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        img.scaleToFit(position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
        img.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft() + (position.getWidth() - img.getScaledWidth()) / 2,
                position.getBottom() + (position.getHeight() - img.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        try {
            canvas.addImage(img);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I created a `PositionEvent` to add the text inside the cell:

```
class PositionEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected Phrase content;
    protected POSITION pos;

    public PositionEvent(Phrase content, POSITION pos) {
        this.content = content;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        int alignment = 0;
        switch (pos) {
            case TOP_LEFT:
                x = position.getLeft(3);
                y = position.getTop(content.getLeading());
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                break;
            case TOP_RIGHT:
                x = position.getRight(3);
                y = position.getTop(content.getLeading());
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
            case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                x = position.getLeft(3);
                y = position.getBottom(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                break;
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                x = position.getRight(3);
                y = position.getBottom(3);
                alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                break;
        }
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, alignment, content, x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

This is how I use these events:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // 1. Create a Document which contains a table:
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
    // 2. Inside that table, make each cell with specific height:
    cell1.setFixedHeight(50);
    cell2.setFixedHeight(50);
    cell3.setFixedHeight(50);
    cell4.setFixedHeight(50);
    // 3. Each cell has the same background image
    ImageEvent imgEvent = new ImageEvent(Image.getInstance(IMG));
    cell1.setCellEvent(imgEvent);
    cell2.setCellEvent(imgEvent);
    cell3.setCellEvent(imgEvent);
    cell4.setCellEvent(imgEvent);
    // 4. Add text in front of the image at specific position
    cell1.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Top left"), POSITION.TOP_LEFT));
    cell2.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Top right"), POSITION.TOP_RIGHT));
    cell3.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Bottom left"), POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT));
    cell4.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase("Bottom right"), POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT));
    // Wrap it all up!
    table.addCell(cell1);
    table.addCell(cell2);
    table.addCell(cell3);
    table.addCell(cell4);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Normally, I would write this code in a more efficient way, but I order the code lines in a way so that they reflect your requirements 1, 2, 3 and 4 literally.

**Update:**

In the comments, you asked several additional questions. For instance: how to stretch the image:

[image]

You were able to answer most of these questions, for instance based on my hint to use `ScaleAbsolute`:

```
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    img.scaleAbsolute(position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
    img.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
    PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
    try {
        canvas.addImage(img);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

You had one more question that required an extra example (it was hard to explain it in a comment box). I named that example [PositionContentInCell2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/PositionContentInCell2)

Instead of using the `POSITION` enumeration, you asked if it was possible to pass `x` and `y` values. You could do that, but you probably won't always know the width and the height of the cells, so why not define percentages such as `wPct` and `hPct`, along with an alignment:

```
class PositionEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected Phrase content;
    protected float wPct;
    protected float hPct;
    protected int alignment;

    public PositionEvent(Phrase content, float wPct, float hPct, int alignment) {
        this.content = content;
        this.wPct = wPct;
        this.hPct = hPct;
        this.alignment = alignment;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        float x = position.getLeft() + wPct * position.getWidth();
        float y = position.getBottom() + hPct * (position.getHeight() - content.getLeading());
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, alignment, content, x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Now you can add these events like this:

```
cell1.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Top left"), 0, 1, Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
cell2.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Top right"), 1, 1, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
cell3.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Top center"), 0.5f, 1, Element.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell4.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Bottom center"), 0.5f, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell5.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Middle center"), 0.5f, 0.5f, Element.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell6.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Middle center"), 0.5f, 0.5f, Element.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell7.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Bottom left"), 0, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
cell8.setCellEvent(new PositionEvent(new Phrase(14, "Bottom right"), 1, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT));
```

Of course, if you prefer passing `x` and `y` (after all: you do know the height, because you are defining a fixed height, the code can be made even simpler: you don't multiple the variables with `position.getWidth` and `position.getHeight()`.

Comment: thank you so much .. that is exactly what I wanted .. and sorry again for confusing you with my requirements

Comment: These are too many questions at once. Split them up in separate questions.

Comment: you want me to post this as a new question ?? .. Sorry but I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @lasheul I think that would be best. For instance: you now use `ScaleToFit`, but what you actually want is `ScaleAbsolute`. There was no way I could know this because you're question wasn't clear. If you use `ScaleAbsolute`, positioning the image as the background of a cell is easier. You can just use `img.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());` because the image will have the exact same dimensions of the cell so there is no need to center it. Nothing in your additional questions is something that can't be solved using common sense.

Comment: So one last question .. is it possible to turn positioning to more flexible way.. for example instead of using switch case and phrases like "bottom left".. Can I use numbers? ,like (x=0 ,y=0) means top left ,and if I use (x=width  ,y= height) it would be bottom right , and middle center means (x=width/2,y=height/2) .. etc

Comment: I'll make another example. It's fairly easy to do that, but I would use percentages rather than `x` and `y` values. My example will explain what I mean, but please give me a moment.

Comment: I can't thank you enough ... based on your example I've managed to make the user choose the position of the text using the mouse .. So thanks again ..

Comment: of course .. I'll do it as soon as I got my 15 reputation ^_^'

Comment: @lasheul Aah... I didn't think of that threshold. I already up voted your question a couple of days ago. I can only vote for it once...